# HyperLink in flash is not working in FireFox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, flash, internet-explorer, firefox

I would like to add HyperLink to my flash banner.
I tried to add a normal tag for hyperlink but it doesn't work so I had to use the following JavaScript function

```
<a id="myFlashLink"><embed src="http://imperialtrader.com/egfinder/logo/red/moto.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="200"></embed></a>

<script>
var anchorflash = document.getElementById('myFlashLink');
anchorflash.onmousedown = function() {
window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_self");
}
</script>
```

This function is working in Chrome but not working in FireFox and IE
Try to copy this code in html file and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add wmode="opaque" in your embed tag.

```
<a id="myFlashLink"><embed src="http://imperialtrader.com/egfinder/logo/red/moto.swf" quality="high" wmode="opaque" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="200"></embed></a>
```

check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34WdU/1/)

Hope this helps